# Wireshark can't decrypt TLS from a specific python library

Tags: tls, python, decryption, wireshark

I have a problem. I'm using Wireshark 4.0.8. I created my ssl file to store my "(pre)-master-secrets". I can thus decrypt TLS from my browser or from different python libraries without problem. But I cannot decrypt the TLS when my requests are made with the TLS-CLIENT python library (https://github.com/FlorianREGAZ/Python-Tls-Client) which allows the use of HTTP/2 and TLS fingerprints of real browsers.

However, I manage to decrypt the requests made with Curl-CFFI ("curl-impersonate" but for python) (https://github.com/yifeikong/curl_cffi) which also copies the HTTP and TLS fingerprints of real browsers. Does anyone have an idea why I can't decrypt TLS when I use the "TLS-Client" python library? (I'm not sure, but it seems that pre master secrets are not written to my ssl file when using this specific library) despite port number 443 on the server is used for the encrypted TLS. It seems that this specific library (Python-Tls-Client) can't write pre master keys in my file. Any solution ? Thanks

Comment: Writing out TLS premaster secrets is a debugging feature, libraries don't have to support it so a program that performs TLS connections without writing  premaster secrets is not unlikely. If you want to make use of the tool you can try to manually extract the secrets using a debugger or a tool like https://frida.re.

Comment: @Robert Thanks for your reply. I tried with Mitmproxy, it also does not intercept requests made with this specific python librairie (based on a Golang library). I'll try with Frida. Thanks for your help